# Flask-Migrate No Changes Detected to Schema on first migration

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm using Flask with Flask-SQLAlchemy and Flask-Migrate to create an application, however when I try to create a migration nothing happens.

I've created two tables in `app/models.py`:

```
from flask import current_app
from . import db

class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Student, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tutor {}>' % self.id

class Tutor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tutors'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tutor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Student %r>' % self.id
```

Then I also have `app/__init__.py` with the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

#from .models import User, Task, Project, UserProject

from config import config

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_name='default'):
    #print config_name.name
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    ## Register the main blueprint for main app functionality
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

and `app.py`:

```
import os
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import Tutor, Student

app = create_app('default')

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return dict(db=db, Tutor=Tutor, Student=Student)
```

I can run `flask db init` with no problem and it creates the migrations directory and all necessary files with the following output:

```
Creating directory /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/flask-tutoring/migrations ... done
Creating directory /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/flask-tutoring/migrations/versions ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/flask-tutoring/migrations/script.py.mako ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/flask-tutoring/migrations/env.py ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/flask-tutoring/migrations/README ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/flask-tutoring/migrations/alembic.ini ... done
Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in '/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/flask-tutoring/migrations/alembic.ini' before proceeding.
```

but when I try and run `flask db migrate` alembic can't detect that I've got tables in `app/models.py`. I get the following output:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.
```

There is no migration script created, its as though `models.py` doesn't exist.

Apologies if this is a repeated question, but I can't find another example where its the first migration that fails and no migration script at all is created.

I've tried checking if there is already a table created somewhere by running `db.drop_all()` in the shell but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

### UPDATE

I figured out a way to solve this on my own but would like a better understanding of why this worked.

I re-named `app.py` to `flasktutor.py` and re-ran `export FLASK_APP='flasktutor.py'`. Subsequently the migration worked perfectly.

Please could someone explain why when the file was called `app.py` and I used `export FLASK_APP='app.py'` the migration did not register changes to the schema.

Comment: There's got to be something else that you changed. I have an application called app.py that I use to test Flask-Migrate and that works perfectly well. If you have a complete example that shows this problem it would be useful if you can share it.

Comment: I have the same problem but my file's name is run.py. I changed it to app.py then to phoenix.py and still the same issue. Debugging the application on this line `app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])` I uncovered that the reference to config_name is throwing the same error when I run the app.
 
`KeyError: <flask.cli.ScriptInfo object at 0x0000000003A11D68>`.

Comment: This was an issue I had, thanks for this, it is to do with flask mixing up a package and a module import of the same name at different points

Answer (score 24):

I encountered this problem and solved it by importing my models at `env.py` in the migrations folder right after the following comments

```
# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata

from app.models import Student, Tutor
```

Answer (score 18):

Pls make sure that you already import your models (Tutor, Student, ...) before your `migrate.init_app(app, db)`

Answer (score 11):

This is how I solved the problem in my case:

1. Import the `Migrate` model: `from flask_migrate import Migrate`
2. Initiate `Migrate` class: `migrate = Migrate(app, db)`
3. Comment `db.create_all()`
4. Drop your database now => `DROP DATABASE db_name;`
5. Create it again => `CREATE DATABSE db_name OWNER owner_name;`
6. Export you flask entry file => `export FLASK_APP=name_app.py`
7. Run `flask db migrate`

Note: The 6th step should be used in case you get this error:

```
Error: Could not locate a Flask application
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thansk for actually telling I had to comment `db.create_all()`.

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into the same issue, following [Miguel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904393/miguel) [great tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database), and the hints here were very helpful!

My solution - which *doesn't* require "hacking" `env.py` - is to simply add

```python
from app import models
```

to `__init__.py`.

If you have a different project layout you might need to adapt the import but it seems like you need to make sure that models gets imported properly for `flask db migrate` to work.

Comment: Perfect! "Imports" were the culprits here. Did not import models before instantiating the Migrate() earlier.

Comment: I was following the same (amazing) tutorial. I'd changed the module name to "bloggy" in order to disambiguate `app`. So my import is `from bloggy import models` and viola table has been created.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I encountered the same problem following Miguel Grinberg tutorial.

Previously I created the tables using the shell calling

```
db.create_all()
```

So, I thougth to drop the tables

```
db.drop_all()
```

and trying the migrate command again, it worked as expected:

```
Roberto@MyPC MINGW64 /e/Projects/Flask/flasky ((5c))
$ flask db migrate -m "initial migration - Role Users"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'roles'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'users'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_users_username' on '['username']'
Generating E:\Projects\Flask\flasky\migrations\versions\4de323c9c089_initial_migration_role_users.py ... done
```

After that, I used flask-migrate to re-create the tables

```
$ flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> b641ee80a60d, initial migration - Role Users
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem following Miguel Grinberg tutorial.
I solved this my adding

```
from app.models import  User, Post
```

to migrations/env.py

Comment: then re run flask db migrate -m "users table"

Answer (score 2):

**The flask-migrate works after you change your table schema.**

Such as, before:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Test(db.Model):
    content = db.Column(db.String(60))
```

and then you change your Test schema, like:

```
class Test(db.Model):
    content = db.Column(db.String(60))
    add = db.Column(db.String(60))
```

**Now, you can use `flask db migrate -m "migrate test"` to work.**

**You will get migrate version information.**

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

In **migrations/env.py**, import your models

```
# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from app.models import * # <= Add this line
from flask import current_app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can point to empty database only to create migration file, then return back to upgrade your real database.

Answer (score 0):

After some time trying to fix it and reading about it, I just deleted the migrations directory (folder) and the app.db.
Then ran again:

1. "flask db init"
2. "flask db migrate"
3. "flask db upgrade"

This re-generate the directories and all working fine now.

If you want to improve your migration script, this link to an upgrade from Miguel, can be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpRVZFwsD70&feature=emb_logo

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know about everyone else; but, none of these fully worked for me.
There is one extra step that did though. (Perhaps it's because I'm using sqlite database).

What I did from app dir:

```
cd instance
rm site.db (sqlite3 database file)
   (note: yours might be different based on your configuration file)
   (but it will likely be the only file in there)
cd ..
rm -rf migrations
flask db init
flask db migrate -m "initial commit"
flask upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have said, add before migrations are initialized. I'm adding another case for migration initialization via constructor:

```py
from app.models import * # first, before initializing migration
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```